# ArrayList is Empty and Getting Error

Tags: android, android-view, android-adapter

I have this in my Fragment extends ListFragment:

```
try {
    FileInputStream in = getActivity().getApplicationContext().openFileInput("list");
    ObjectInputStream i = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    myData = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, MessageRecord>>) i.readObject();
    if (myData != null) {
        this.totalmessages = myData.size();
        mySimpleAdapter = new MySimpleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),  myData, R.layout.menurow, mStrings, new int [] {R.id.ivDirection, R.id.tvMessage});
        setListAdapter(mySimpleAdapter);
    }
    in.close();
   }
```

I am getting this errors:

```
Error: Fetch Message List
Error: java.lang.NullPointException
Error: ...FragmentMessages$1.run(FragmentMessages.java:307)
```

This last line is pointing to

```
mySimpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please help.

Comment: full log cat please with FragmentMessages.java class ..........

Comment: `if(null!=mySimpleAdapter){mySimpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}`

Comment: Ensure that the `mySimpleAdapter!=null` before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

call [`notifyDataSetInvalidated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetInvalidated%28%29) if the array is empty, and `notifyDataSetChanged()` if the array is not empty.

To clarify a bit more, in case your data is empty and have set an [emptyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) on the listView, `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` will bring up the empty view. 
The error you are getting is because upon calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the adapter is trying to conjure a listView view while there is no data, so therefore can't construct that view.